# AmMaps is not registering clickMapObject

Tags: javascript, ammap

I'm having trouble getting AmMaps to execute a function when I click on a state. [Here's my code.](http://codepen.io/DawnPaladin/pen/qnCxL) This line is not operating as I expect it to:

```
map.addListener("clickMapObject", function(event) {
```

When I shorten `"clickMapObject"` to just `"click"`, the function works fine. But I need `clickMapObject` so the map will be able to tell me which state I've clicked on; if I use `click` it will only give me lat/long coordinates. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got a response back from AmCharts support:

> Just to clarify, if the area/state/country does not have any actions
>   attach to it upon click (zoom, url, description, etc.) it does not
>   generate any click events.
>
> In this case you need to explicitly make all such "inactive" areas
>   clickable by either setting "selectable" property for each area
>   individually or globally via AreasSettings:
>
> http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapArea#selectable
>
> http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AreasSettings#selectable
>
> The latter is probably more universal if you want all areas to
>   generate click event:
>
> ```
> map.areasSettings = { 
>   rollOverColor: "#009ce0" 
>   selectable: true
> };
> ```
>
> I hope it helps.

And it did help. Adding `selectable: true` to my `map.areasSettings` object did the trick!